# Composing of delegates (functional pitfall)

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates

When trying to use delegates in C# to solve a problem in a functional way, I've come across a pitfall that I want to share resp. for which I would like to hear your suggestions.

**Background**

I want to fill a grid from a list of objects where the values for single columns are get using delegates (idea borrowed from [Philip Pipers ObjectListView control](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)).

Additionally I want to automatically insert columns containing the (numerical) difference between two values.

So my objects having properties `FirstValue`, `SecondValue` and `ThirdValue` I want to have columns with `FirstValue`, `(SecondValue-FirstValue)`, `SecondValue`, `(ThirdValue-SecondValue)`, `ThirdValue`.

I already have adapted an existing grid control to use delegates on an object list, this part works fine.

**First attempt**

First, I tried something like:

```
class MyGridClass : DelegateGrid
{
  DelegateGrid.ValueGetter lastGetter;

  public MyGridClass() {
    AddMyColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { return obj.FirstValue; });
    AddMyColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { return obj.SecondValue; });
    AddMyColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { return obj.ThirdValue; });
  }

  private void AddMyColumn(DelegateGrid.ValueGetter getter) {
    if (lastGetter != null)
      base.AddColumn(new DelegateColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { 
        return getter(obj)-lastGetter(obj); 
      }));
    base.AddColumn(new DelegateColumn(getter));
  }
};
```

**Problem**

In a functional language, calculating the difference in this way would work fine, since the new delegate (constructed inside `AddMyColumn`) would use the *value* of `lastGetter` at the time of construction. But in C#, the new delegate uses a *reference* to `lastGetter`, so when executed, it uses the actual value at the time of execution. So the difference will always be built against the last column (i.e. `obj.ThirdValue`).

**Solution**

One solution I've found for myself is

```
public AddMyColumn(DelegateGrid.ValueGetter getter) {
  if (lastGetter != null) {
    DelegateGrid.ValueGetter newLastGetter = 
      new DelegateGrid.ValueGetter(lastGetter);
    base.AddColumn(new DelegateColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { 
     return getter(obj)-newLastGetter(obj); 
    }));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Note that

```
if (lastGetter != null) {
  DelegateGrid.ValueGetter newLastGetter = 
    delegate(MyObject obj){return lastGetter(obj); };
```

wouldn't have solved the problem.

**Question**

Already having found a solution, this part is a bit pro forma, but

- Does anyone have a suggestion for a better solution
- I'm using C#2.0 and have only a theoretical knowledge of lambda expressions in C#3.0: Would they allow for a cleaner solution (and thus deserve their name...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is just that the *variable* is being captured rather than the value. Here's a solution which is much the same, but slightly simpler:

```
public AddMyColumn(DelegateGrid.ValueGetter getter) {
  if (lastGetter != null) {
    DelegateGrid.ValueGetter newLastGetter = lastGetter;
    base.AddColumn(new DelegateColumn(delegate(MyObj obj) { 
     return getter(obj)-newLastGetter(obj); 
    }));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Basically there's no need to create a new delegate instance - delegates are immutable, so you can just copy the value with assignment.

This isn't really a delegate-specific problem in terms of the value being captured - it's a common problem for anonymous methods and lambda expressions in general. The typical example is;

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
foreach (Action action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

This prints "10" 10 times. To print 0-9, you again need to change the scope of the captured variable:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(copy));
}
foreach (Action action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other points, lambda syntax is going to make it much nicer, since they'll reduce the verbose code.

```
delegate(MyObj obj) { 
    return getter(obj)-newLastGetter(obj); 
}
```

Becomes:

```
obj => getter(obj)-newLastGetter(obj)
```